# Whole word search in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to perform a whole word search in javascript using the following regex.

```
str = "Test String C.S (example)";
var regex_search = new RegExp("\\b"+search_string+"\\b","g");
if(str.match(regex_search)) != null)
  match = true;
else
  match = false;
```

The above works well if I search for a normal string like 'String'. But if I search for just 'S', it returns C.S as a match. Also, searching for example returns a match but in this case I do not want a match because it has parenthesis. I just want to match the whole word only. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

--Edit--

Thanks to @plalx Clarified the example.

Comment: It's not possible that `/\bS\b/` returns `['S.C']` as a match. Do you mean that you want to match `S` only when it's *alone* as in `'something S something'`?

Comment: Actually, Yes. /\bS\b/ does return S.C as a match. Or even U.S or A'S

Comment: You mean that `console.log("Test String S.C (example)".match(/\bS\b/));` prints out `['S.C']`? I am sure that it isin't the case. Perhaps you are misinterpreting the term `return`.

Comment: You have to define more precisely what a "word" is. That might sound silly, but computers are like that.

Comment: @Nash3man I updated my answer with a potential solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use capture groups?

```
.*?\b(S)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](http://www.debuggex.com/r/lUsQMz382TVLmX0t)

I think your second `\b` is breaking your code also.

Just replace the (`S`) with value you want to find.

Not really sure exactly what you're asking to be honest. Or what you are trying to find.

**edit:**

```
.*?(?:^|\s)(S[^\s$]*).*?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](http://www.debuggex.com/r/_SZn1oGNEtQCbgiA)

you can prob take out the `.*?` at the start and the end of the regex put it in there for thoroughness.

replace the `S` in front of `[^\s$]` with the value you want to check.
Also, if you want to allow more things in front of the value all you have to do is add an extra `|"character"` in the first capture group.

for example a parenthesis

```
.*?(?:^|\s|\()
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. should have given a better example. If my search term is 'S' and the string is 'C.S', it still returns a true though S is not the start of the string. I'm trying to check the beginning of each word. For example, if my string is "This is it" and I search for 'is', it should print only 'is' and not 'this'

Comment: Thank you very much. From the demo, it pretty much does what I'm asking for. Just wanted to confirm if I'm writing it right when I do it in javascript.                                                                 var regex_search = new RegExp(".*?(?:^|\\s)("+search_string+"  [^\\s$]*).*?","g");

Comment: @Nash3man, As far as I can see `/.*?(?:^|\s)(S[^\s$]*).*?/.test('S.C')` returns `true`. Wasn't this your previous issue?

Comment: @plalx It was when the string was `C.S` `S.C` should return true.

Comment: My bad. I was going to write C.S and ended up with S.C. But just realized after you pointed out that if my search term is 'S.C' and the string is 'Security', it still returns true which should have returned false instead.

Answer (score 4):

Word boundaries are all non-word characters, which includes the `.` character. You will have to use something else than `\b`.

I am sure the regex can be simplified, but you could use something like:

```
function containsWord(string, word) {
    return new RegExp('(?:[^.\w]|^|^\\W+)' + word + '(?:[^.\w]|\\W(?=\\W+|$)|$)').test(string);
}

containsWord('test', 'test'); //true
containsWord('.test', 'test'); //true
containsWord('test.something', 'test'); //false
containsWord('test. something', 'test'); //true
containsWord('test.   something', 'test'); //true
containsWord('S.C', 'S'); //false
containsWord('S.C', 'S.C'); //true
```