# How I can find the exact number with js?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm doing some work for my class, and I think I can help because I am a rookie. It's a finder html + javascript + json

I get it to search an exact number, because if you look for "0202" results appear as "102021" and need to find the exact number

I appreciate any help

This is code:

```
    var globalbusqueda;

function reemplazar(cadena, busca, reemplaza) {
    while (cadena.toString().indexOf(busca) != -1) cadena = cadena.toString().replace(busca, reemplaza);
    return cadena
}

function ncaracteres(cadena) {
    return cadena.length
}
window.onload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    var that = null;
    var jsearch = function () {
        this.automatically = false;
        this.items = [];
        this.itemsFound = [];
        this.totalPages = 0;
        this.currentPaginator = 0;
        this.busy = false;
        this.latesSearch = null;
        this.blockScreen = true;
        this.move = false;
        this.ismobile = this.detectBrowser();
        that = this
    };
    jsearch.prototype.init = function () {
        document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
            if (that.blockScreen) e.preventDefault()
        }, false);
        if (!this.ismobile) document.documentElement.style.overflow = "scroll";

        function getHTTPObject() {
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined") return new XMLHttpRequest;
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                } catch (e) {}
            }
            return false
        }
        var url = null;
        if (this.automatically) url = "js/databasefolder.js?v=" + (new Date).getTime();
        else url = "js/db.JSON?v=" + (new Date).getTime();
        this.get("loading").style.display = "block";
        var http = getHTTPObject();
        http.open("GET", url, false);
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (http.readyState === 4) {
                that.items = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
                that.show()
            }
        };
        http.send(null)
    };
    jsearch.prototype.show = function () {
        this.get("loading").style.display = "none";
        this.get("wrapper").style.display = "block";
        this.get("found").style.display = "block";
        this.get("paginator").style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.addClass(that.get("wrapper"), "initWeb");
            that.listeners();
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.blockScreen = false;
                withSlopeFinite(that.get("found"))
            }, 1)
        }, 1)
    };
    jsearch.prototype.listeners = function () {
        var element = that.get("searchForm");
        if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener("submit", submitForm, false);
        else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent("onsubmit", submitForm, false);

        function submitForm(eventObject) {
            if (eventObject.preventDefault) eventObject.preventDefault();
            else if (window.event) window.event.returnValue = false;
            var valueSearch = document.forms.searchForm.search.value;
            cantidadcaracteres = ncaracteres(valueSearch);
            if (cantidadcaracteres >= 3) {
                valueSearch = reemplazar(valueSearch, ".", "");



                globalbusqueda = valueSearch;
                var validateSearch = that.trim(valueSearch);
                if (!that.busy && (validateSearch !== "" && that.latesSearch !== validateSearch)) {
                    that.busy = true;
                    that.find()
                }
            }
        }
        var arrowPrevious = this.get("arrowPrevious");
        arrowPrevious.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var isDisabled = that.hasClass(this, "disabled");
            if (!isDisabled && that.move) {
                that.move = false;
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                that.get("section" + that.currentPaginator).style.display = "none";
                that.currentPaginator--;
                that.get("section" + that.currentPaginator).style.display = "inline-block";
                that.get("currentPages").innerHTML = "P&aacute;gina " + that.currentPaginator + " de " + that.totalPages;
                if (that.currentPaginator === 1) that.addClass(this, " disabled");
                if (that.currentPaginator < that.totalPages) that.removeClass(that.get("arrowNext"), "disabled");
                that.move = true
            }
        });
        var arrowNext = this.get("arrowNext");
        arrowNext.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var isDisabled = that.hasClass(this, "disabled");
            if (!isDisabled && that.move) {
                that.move = false;
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                that.get("section" + that.currentPaginator).style.display = "none";
                that.currentPaginator++;
                that.get("section" + that.currentPaginator).style.display = "inline-block";
                that.get("currentPages").innerHTML = "P&aacute;gina " + that.currentPaginator + " de " + that.totalPages;
                if (that.totalPages == that.currentPaginator) that.addClass(this, " disabled");
                if (that.currentPaginator > 1) that.removeClass(that.get("arrowPrevious"), "disabled");
                that.move = true
            }
        })
    };
    jsearch.prototype.find = function () {
        this.get("loading").style.display = "block";
        if (this.ismobile) document.forms.searchForm.search.blur();
        this.itemsFound = [];
        this.removeClass(this.get("paginator"), "initWeb");
        this.removeClass(this.get("found"), "initWeb");
        this.addClass(this.get("logo"), "closeLogo");
        setTimeout(function () {
            var matchString = globalbusqueda;
            that.latesSearch = matchString;
            if (that.items.length > 0)
                for (var k in that.items) {
                    if (that.items[k].title.toLowerCase().match(matchString.toLowerCase()) || (that.items[k].description.toLowerCase().match(matchString.toLowerCase()) || that.items[k].claves.toLowerCase().match(matchString.toLowerCase()) || that.items[k].original.toLowerCase().match(matchString.toLowerCase()))) that.itemsFound.push(that.items[k]);
                    if (k == that.items.length - 1) {
                        that.get("loading").style.display = "none";
                        that.appendElements(that.itemsFound)
                    }
                } else {
                    that.busy = false;
                    that.get("loading").style.display = "none";
                    that.get("found").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-info">¡No se encontraron resultados!</div>';
                    that.addClass(that.get("found"), "initWeb")
                }
        }, 1E3)
    };
    jsearch.prototype.appendElements = function () {
        this.resetPaginator();
        this.get("found").innerHTML = "";
        var totalData = this.itemsFound.length;
        var show = 10;
        var amountToSee = totalData / show;
        amountToSee = amountToSee.toString();
        amountToSee = amountToSee.split(".");
        if (amountToSee[1]) {
            if (amountToSee[0] == 0) this.addClass(this.get("arrowNext"), " disabled");
            else this.addClass(this.get("paginator"), "initWeb");
            amountToSee = amountToSee[0];
            amountToSee++;
            this.totalPages = amountToSee
        } else if (amountToSee[0] == 0) {
            this.get("found").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-info">¡No se encontraron resultados!</div>';
            this.addClass(this.get("found"), "initWeb")
        } else {
            if (amountToSee[0] == 1) this.removeClass(this.get("arrowNext"), "disabled");
            this.totalPages = amountToSee
        }
        var current = 0;
        for (var s = 1; s <= amountToSee; s++) {
            var divFound = this.get("found");
            divFound.innerHTML = divFound.innerHTML + '<div id="section' + s + '" class="itemResult"></div>';
            for (var i = current * show; i <= show * s - 1; i++)
                if (that.itemsFound[i]) {
                    var divSection = this.get("section" + s);
                    divSection.innerHTML = divSection.innerHTML + '<div class="itemResultado"><a target="_parent" href=' + that.itemsFound[i].link + ">" + that.itemsFound[i].title + '<div class="linkGreen">' + that.itemsFound[i].link + "</div><div class='linkBlue'>" + that.itemsFound[i].original + "</div></a></div>" + that.itemsFound[i].description + "<br></div></div>" ;
                    if (i == show * s - 1) current++
                }
            if (amountToSee == s) {
                this.get("currentPages").innerHTML = "P&aacute;gina " + that.currentPaginator + " de " + that.totalPages;
                that.addClass(this.get("found"), "initWeb");
                that.addClass(this.get("paginator"), "initWeb");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    that.move = true
                }, 1E3)
            }
        }
    };
    jsearch.prototype.resetPaginator = function () {
        this.totalPages = 0;
        this.currentPaginator = 1;
        this.get("currentPages").innerHTML = "P&aacute;gina " + this.currentPaginator;
        this.removeClass(this.get("arrowNext"), "disabled");
        var isDisabled = this.hasClass(that.get("arrowPrevious"), "disabled");
        if (!isDisabled) that.addClass(this.get("arrowPrevious"), " disabled");
        this.busy = false
    };
    jsearch.prototype.addItem = function (title, link, original, description,  claves) {
        this.items.push({
            "title": title,
            "link": link,
            "original": original,
            "description": description,

            "claves": claves
        })
    };
    jsearch.prototype.hasClass = function (ele, cls) {
        return ele.className.match(new RegExp("(\\s|^)" + cls + "(\\s|$)"))
    };

    jsearch.prototype.addClass = function (ele, cls) {
        if (!this.hasClass(ele, cls)) ele.className += cls
    };
    jsearch.prototype.removeClass = function (ele, cls) {
        if (this.hasClass(ele, cls)) {
            var reg = new RegExp("(\\s|^)" + cls + "(\\s|$)");
            ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg, "");

        }
    };
    jsearch.prototype.trim = function (string) {
        return string.replace(/^\s+/g, "").replace(/\s+$/g, "")

    };

    jsearch.prototype.get = function (obj) {
        return document.getElementById(obj)
    };
    jsearch.prototype.detectBrowser = function () {
        var ismobile = /iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|opera|mini|windows\sce|palm|smartphone|iemobile|msie/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
        return ismobile
    };
    search = new jsearch;
    search.init()
};
```

Comment: Don't use `.match`, use `==`.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878143/whole-word-search-in-javascript-using-regex

Answer (score 0):

You're using `.match()` to compare the search string with the values, which does a regular expression match. You should just use `==` to do an exact comparison.

```
var matchLower = matchString.toLowerCase();
if (that.items[k].title.toLowerCase().match == matchLower || (that.items[k].description.toLowerCase() == matchLower || that.items[k].claves.toLowerCase() == matchLower || that.items[k].original.toLowerCase() == matchLower)
    that.itemsFound.push(that.items[k]);
```